# Python Gives me empty output

Tags: python

At first I thought PythonScriptor was the problem, but I tried `print('Hello World')` and the output was fine.When ever I copy and paste a code it just gives me an empty line. I am currently learning Subroutines in Python, but I completely don't get it.

```
def myFirstSubroutine():
    for i in range(1,3):
        print('This is a subroutine')
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling your function? In the code you posted, all you do is define it.

Answer (score 3):

The code snippet you just showed us *defined* the function. To execute the function, now you need to *call* it.

```
>>> myFirstSubroutine()
This is a subroutine
This is a subroutine
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Where did you type this? Did you exclude the `>>>` characters (those are simply the prompt characters in IDLE, you don't need those).

Comment: Yes I obviously excluded the characters. But 'myfirstsubroutine' is not defined.

Comment: Did you type it as you just did in your comment? If so capitalization is important in Python. `myfirstsubroutine != myFirstSubroutine`

Comment: @jeff. And then it worked? everything works for me in my idle when declaring and calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CoryKramer for his right answer. You need to call the function `myFirstSubroutine()` to get the output.

Pay attention to that lowercase letter variable is not equal to capital letter variable in Python. That means you need to use exact the function name `myFirstSubroutine()`.

As well as *'I copied what you gave me , it doesn't work.'*, it can work if you really copy it instead of spelling the 'myfirstsubroutine' by yourself.